# Using htaccess to redirect all pages but one to another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My htaccess is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.es$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.es$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/es [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?section=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Basically it's function is to redirect all domain alias (i.e. domain.mobi) to domain.com, except domain.es, that will be redirected to domain.com/es. Then there's another rewriterule that appends the query string (so in the background, domain.com/test becomes domain.com/index.php?section=test)

My problem is that now I need to exclude a url (www.domain.es/landing) from the redirection (so it stays in domain.es), and I can't make it work. I've tried adding this condition to the first two rules to exclude the page:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/landing$
```

but then it goes to www.domain.com/es?section=landing (not only still redirects to domain.com; the query string appears in the browser bar). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.es$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/landing[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/es/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/landing[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?section=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That almost works; www.domain.es/landing stays but it shows a 404 page, I suppose that it's because the last rule  (the one with index.php) it's not applied.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but nope, still not working, now it goes to www.domain.com/es/index.php?section=landing

Comment: Yep, that works better, it stays in the page and shows the content, however now all the images and stylesheets are broken as they all redirect to domain.com. I'll try to add some additional REQUEST_FILENAME condition to see if it works

Comment: It is due to your 2nd redirect rule that redirects everything not on `domain.com` to `domain.com`. If you want to skip files/directories from that rule then add both `REQUEST_FILENAME` conditions on that rule as well.

Comment: It worked adding it before the first rule. Thanks a lot for your help!